# How to select the entire REMOTE file during mergetool?

Tags: git, vim, merge, vimdiff, mergetool

I'm using CLI mergetool `vimdiff` and rather than going line by line and typing `:diffg RE` for every change to select the REMOTE version, is there a way I can just have the REMOTE version of the entire file as the target merge?

Comment: Git lets you specify merge strategies (ours, theirs) but these affect the entire merge. Be careful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short answer:

Use `:%diffget` to get all chunks.

---

### Explanation:

`diffget` takes - as most vim commands - a range. To quote vimhelp:

```
                                                        :diffg :diffget
:[range]diffg[et] [bufspec]
                Modify the current buffer to undo difference with another
                buffer.  [...]
                See below for [range].

[...]

When no [range] is given, the diff at the cursor position or just above it is
affected.  When [range] is used, Vim tries to only put or get the specified
lines.
```

`%` when used as a range is "equal to 1,$ (the entire file)", see `:help :%`.

Answer (score 3):

*(CLI alternative)*

I'm aware it doesn't really answer your question as is, but if what you need is to **take everything from one side for a specific conflicting file in a merge**, you don't even need a tool.

You can check out the file version you want (check doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---ours) and [there](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203)) and then `add` it to resolve the conflict :

```
git checkout --ours path/to/file
# or
git checkout --theirs path/to/file

# and then to conclude the resolution
git add path/to/file
```

Note that you can also, if you regret that move, take it back to the unmerged state with conflict markers, with

```
git checkout -m path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

In mergetool, if you have more than 2 buffers, you can't use `:diffget`, as Vim does not know from which file to get the diff from.

However, when you solve a conflict (you need to have `mergetool` running), you have a few files created by Git to manage the conflict:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   my/conflicting/file.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .env
    my/conflicting/file.py.orig
    my/conflicting/file_BACKUP_5038.py
    my/conflicting/file_BASE_5038.py
    my/conflicting/file_LOCAL_5038.py
    my/conflicting/file_REMOTE_5038.py
```

They represent different sides of the conflict:

- BACKUP is a copy of the file with the conflicts markers,
- LOCAL is your current state before the conflict,
- BASE contains the state of the file at the common ancestor commit between your local and the one being merged (or applied in case of rebase, cherry-pick or stash pop/apply),
- REMOTE is the commit trying to be applied <--- which is the version you want in your case

So what you can do is to copy the `_REMOTE_` file as your current (`cp path/to/file_REMOTE_* path/to/file`), or in mergetool, copy the content of `_REMOTE_` (`:%y`) and replace the content of your file with it (`ggVGp`, go at the top, go in visual line mode, go to the end, paste).